# How to check or repair file system on network volume?

Tags: disk-utility, disk-volume

I've an application (Arq7 from `arqbackup.com`) reporting some file system errors…

```
19-Feb-2021 22:04:43 EST Error: /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2011 _General.photoslibrary/resources/recovery.remove-3DBCC166-3954-4988-8185-A8D998BD38F5/RKVersion: failed to get size of extended attributes of /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2011 _General.photoslibrary/resources/recovery.remove-3DBCC166-3954-4988-8185-A8D998BD38F5/RKVersion: Input/output error
19-Feb-2021 22:04:43 EST Error: /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2011 _General.photoslibrary/resources/recovery.remove-3DBCC166-3954-4988-8185-A8D998BD38F5/RKFaceGroup: failed to get size of extended attributes of /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2011 _General.photoslibrary/resources/recovery.remove-3DBCC166-3954-4988-8185-A8D998BD38F5/RKFaceGroup: Input/output error
19-Feb-2021 22:04:43 EST Error: /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2011 _General.photoslibrary/resources/recovery.remove-3DBCC166-3954-4988-8185-A8D998BD38F5/RKMemoryCuratedVersion/0000000000.lij: failed to get size of extended attributes of /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2011 _General.photoslibrary/resources/recovery.remove-3DBCC166-3954-4988-8185-A8D998BD38F5/RKMemoryCuratedVersion/0000000000.lij: Input/output error
19-Feb-2021 22:04:44 EST Error: /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2009 _General.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources/78/67/RKVersion: failed to get size of extended attributes of /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2009 _General.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources/78/67/RKVersion: Input/output error
19-Feb-2021 22:04:44 EST Error: /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2009 _General.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources/78/67/RKFaceGroup: failed to get size of extended attributes of /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2009 _General.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources/78/67/RKFaceGroup: Input/output error
19-Feb-2021 22:04:45 EST Error: /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2009 _General.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources/78/67/RKMemoryCuratedVersion/0000000000.lij: failed to get size of extended attributes of /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ being deleted/2009 _General.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources/78/67/RKMemoryCuratedVersion/0000000000.lij: Input/output error
```

From a terminal, on my Mac with that volume mounted, those directories appear empy (via ls) but I cannot remove them:

```
Craigs-iMac:~ craig$ cd /Volumes/Europa/Photography/µ\ being\ deleted/
Craigs-iMac:µ being deleted craig$ ls
total 2272
drwx------ 1 craig staff 16384 Jun 19 2020 .
drwx------ 1 craig staff 16384 Jan 8 19:54 ..
-rwx------@ 1 craig staff 8196 Jun 19 2020 .DS_Store
drwx------@ 1 craig staff 16384 Jun 19 2020 2009 _General.photoslibrary
drwx------@ 1 craig staff 16384 Jun 19 2020 2011 _General.photoslibrary
drwx------@ 1 craig staff 16384 Jun 19 2020 2012 Las Vegas.photoslibrary
drwx------@ 1 craig staff 16384 Jun 19 2020 2015 Italy.photoslibrary
drwx------@ 1 craig staff 16384 Jun 19 2020 BWC Slides.photoslibrary
Craigs-iMac:µ being deleted craig$ 'rm' -rf 2009\ _General.photoslibrary/
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources/78/67/RKFaceGroup: Input/output error
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources/78/67/RKVersion: Input/output error
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources/78/67/RKMemoryCuratedVersion/0000000000.lij: Input/output error
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources/78/67/RKMemoryCuratedVersion: Directory not empty
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources/78/67: Directory not empty
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources/78: Directory not empty
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources/modelresources: Directory not empty
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary//resources: Directory not empty
rm: 2009 _General.photoslibrary/: Directory not empty
```

Is there any way I can do a file system repair to clean this up?

The mounted volume is on a Drobo but I don't see any way to run file system repair *on* the Drobo...

Comment: Is this a directly connected (ie USB)  drobo or a network Drobo ie using ethernet

Comment: If this is on a NAS then you likely have to do any repairs on the NAS itself unless Drobo supplies software to do it remotely, which I would doubt. Often rebooting the NAS will do a filesystem check, at the very least.